# Help parsing json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have some really simple json I need to parse and then run conditional statements on.  The json looks like:

```
thejson(
{"catalog.exists":"0"},"");
```

And I am trying to parse it with:

```
$('.clicky').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://myjsonfile.com',
        data: 'req=exists,json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (results) {
        var x= catalog.exists;
        $("#results").append(x);
        }

        });
    });
```

However I just get an error that thejson is not defined.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: looks like you're trying to call a function `thejson({...});` rather then assigning it as a variable: `var thejson = {...};`

Comment: Just to be sure, did you mean `results.catalog.exists`? Because there's no reason catalog.exists would reference what you want at this context; I'm not even sure catalog.exists is valid JSON.

Comment: that json is what i have to work with, i think it is valid but i am not sure

Comment: `{"catalog.exists":"0"}` is valid JSON, but `thejson({"catalog.exists":"0"},"");` is not. It looks like a function call.

Comment: Any string for key is valid, you could even put an empty string there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).  It is a retrieval technique to allow JavaScript code to call for and receive JSON data from an external domain.

**`thejson` is the callback function, which you will need to define in your JavaScript code** (it is the absence of this function that is causing the error).  Then, that JSON/JavaScript you are getting back needs to be inserted in script tag into the DOM.  At that point the `thejson` function will be called with the JSON object as a parameter.

[jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) can make JSONP [easy to handle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/).

You probably want something like this:

```
function thejson(response) {
              var x= response["catalog.exists"];
              $("#results").append(x);
}

$('.clicky').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://myjsonfile.com',
        data: 'req=exists,json',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        });
    });
```